# Issue Inserting MySQL Record With Node.js and Handlebars

Tags: mysql, node.js, handlebars.js

I am having an issue when trying to submit a form with user information that inserts into a table. I have a userForm that allows user data to be entered with the following:

```
<form id="userForm">
        <fieldset>
            <legend>Add User</legend>
            <p>First Name: <input id="fname" type="text" name="fname"/></p>
            <p>Last Name: <input  id="lname" type="text" name="lname"/></p>
            <p>Email: <input id="email" type="text" name="email"/></p>
            <p>Password: <input id="password" type="text" name="password"/></p>
        </fieldset>
        <input id="addUser" type="submit" name="add" value="Add User" onclick="addRow()" />
</form>

<script src="script.js"></script>
```

This then launches the following code in my `script.js` code:

```
function addRow(){

    var form = document.getElementById("userForm");

    var req = new XMLHttpRequest();

          // Add the form data to the ajax request
          var queryString = "";

          var fname = form.fname.value;
          var lname = form.lname.value;
          var email = form.email.value;
          var password = form.password.value;

          queryString += "fname=" + fname + "&";
          queryString += "lname=" + lname + "&";
          queryString += "email=" + email + "&";
          queryString += "password=" + password;

          req.open('GET', '/insert-user?' + queryString, true);
          req.send();
          console.log(req.status);
```

Which executes the server side code:

```
app.get('/add-user', function(req,res){
  var context = {};
  res.render('addUser', context);
});

app.get('/insert-user',function(req,res,next){
  var context = {};
  pool.query("INSERT INTO user (`fname`, `lname`, `email`, `password`) VALUES (?,?,?,?)", 
  [req.query.fname, req.query.lname, req.query.email, req.query.password], 
  function(err, result){
    if(err){
      next(err);
      return;
    }
    context.results = "Inserted id " + result.insertId;
    res.render('exerciseTable',context);
  });
});
```

The record is not being inserted into the table. When I `console.log(req.status)` I see 0 in the console. The add-user page is the form that the user fills out and then the insert-user code is called but it does not seem to be working. In fact, the URL does not change from `http://18.219.103.143:3000/add-user` to `http://18.219.103.143:3000/insert-user?` when I submit. It just stays static. It seems like my `app.get('/insert-user'...` code isn't even being called. Does anyone know what I am missing?

I am getting this error in the console:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try to put

```
<form id="userForm" onsubmit="return false;">
```

Otherwise the default action on your form will be called. As your button is a submit button and that your default action is not set so it defaults to the same page and returning nothing or true will reload your page.

Comment: I tried both options and I can't seem to get the record to insert into the user table.

Comment: I am getting a server error on req.send() (see image). Is it possible I'm not connecting to the server correctly?

Comment: You're actually having a server error, try to determine what call fails on your server by first getting the call that is done (in the network view you'll see the call)

Comment: I've updated the answer as my first answer was irrelevant. Take a look at it and it should solve your javascript part at least.

Comment: Thank you for the feedback. It seems like it is this call that is failing `add-user:17 GET http://18.219.103.143:3000/insert-user?fname=new&lname=user&email=ejw&password=hsdf`

Comment: OK you'll have to check on your server then why it is failing. Now is your code addRow executed without reloading the page ?